# How to form Matrix pairs of $m$ friends and to find common friend from all possible pairs.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The below is a problem given in entrance exam.

Problem:
A golf club has $m$ members with serial numbers $1, 2 . . . , m$. If members with serial numbers $i$ and $j$ are friends, then $A(i, j) = A(j, i) = 1$, otherwise $A(i, j) = A(j, i) = 0$. By convention, $A(i, i) = 0$, i.e. a person is not considered a friend of himself or herself. Let $A^k$$(i, j)$ refer to the $(i, j)$th entry in the $k^{th}$ power of the matrix $A$.
Suppose it is given that $A^9(i, j) > 0$ for all pairs $i,j$ where $1 ≤ i,j ≤ m$, $A^2$$(1,2) > 0$ and $A^4(1, 3) = 0$.

Suppose it is given that $A^9(i,j) > 0$ for all pairs $i,j$ where $1 ≤ i,j ≤ m, A^2(1,2) > 0$ and $A^4(1,3) = 0$.

Determine if below problem statements are necessarily true and please provide the reasons for it.

1. Does members $1$ and $2$ have at least one friend in common.
2. $m≤9$
3. $m≥6$
4. $A^2(i,i)> 0$ for all $i$, $1≤i≤m.$

$\\$

My approach:
I tried to form the question in $A(i, j)$ pairs as per the question.

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
(i, j) & \text{1} & \text{2} & \cdots \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots \\
2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\end{array}
$$

Given that $A^2(1, 2) > 0$ and $A$ gives the below matrix.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  0&1\\
  1&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

And $A^2$ gives the below matrix.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&0\\
  0&1
\end{array}
\right] $$

Determinant of this gives 1.

I could not proceed further as I am still not sure if my approach to this problem is correct or not.

Can someone please explain the approach to this problem and also let me know if there exists a book which contains these type of problems which would help me a lot.

Comment: This is my first question so please correct my mistakes if there are any.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what the question is? I.e, what is demanded in the problem?

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic We need to find the least 'm' value and does members 1 and 2 have at least one friend in common.

Comment: This is another one. $ A^2(i,i)>0, for all i,1≤i≤m.$

Comment: We need to tell if the given question is true or not and provide a reason for it.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Any other details required?

Comment: No, it's good. Thank you, I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: It is still not clear which part of your post is the problem and which is your attempts to solve it.

Comment: @Vladislav I have edited the part. Please have a look and let me know if its clear

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but some thoughts. 
 
The well-known fact (you can easily prove it by induction) is that $k$th power of adjacency matrix $A$ is a matrix of pathes that have length $k$.  Thus, $A^{k}(i, j)$ equals to number of pathes from $i$ to $j$ that have length $k$. In this terms, $A^9(i, j) > 0$ means there is a path from $i$ to $j$ of length 9, $A^2(1, 2) > 0$ means there is a path from $1$ to $2$ of length 2, and $A^4(1, 3) = 0$ means there is no path from $1$ to $3$ of length 4. Now, this

> members $1$ and $2$ have at least one friend in common.

immediatly follows from $A^2(1, 2) > 0$ as you have a path $1 \to x \to2$ and $x$ is a common friend for $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea about Graph Theory. Now I will learn.